# Convert Warning to Error

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, gcc

In Windows, VC++ has a nifty option [/We](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thxezb7y.aspx) to convert a specific warning to error. Also every warning emitted by VC++ has a warning number for example

```
warning C4265: 'CFoo' : class has virtual functions, but destructor is not virtual
```

So it easy to identify the number and add a compiler option using the [/We](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thxezb7y.aspx) switch as /We4265

I checked the g++ documentation and found something similar (I believe), [-Werror=](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html), but the documentation mentions

> Make the specified warning into an error.

But my question is,

Given a compiler warning

```
/yada/yada/src/inc/module.h:580: warning: 'struct IFoo' has virtual functions but non-virtual destructor
```

How do I convert this to error using the `-Werror` compiler option?

Comment: -Werror in your makefile ;)

Comment: which version of `g++` do you use?

Answer (score 3):

That very sentence [in the manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options) continues, with the answer:

> The specifier for a warning is appended; for example `-Werror=switch` turns the warnings controlled by `-Wswitch` into errors. This switch takes a negative form, to be used to negate `-Werror` for specific warnings; for example `-Wno-error=switch` makes `-Wswitch` warnings not be errors, even when `-Werror` is in effect.

I'm not 100% sure, but `-Wdelete-non-virtual-dtor` might be the warning in question, so you'd need `-Werror=delete-non-virtual-dtor`.

Answer (score 1):

Compile the code with a later version of g++ or Clang++, they emit the name of the warnings as well.

```
$ clang++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror=non-virtual-dtor test.cpp
test10.cpp:4:3: error: 'X' has virtual functions but non-virtual destructor
      [-Wnon-virtual-dtor]
  ~X(){}
  ^
1 error generated.
```

Answer (score 1):

Either specify `-Werror` without any arguments to turn all warnings into errors, thus also the one above you're interested in. If you're only interested in turning that specific warning into an error, you can cause g++ to print the error switch in verbose mode. Newer versions of g++ even do this automatically.