# GCC & Cmake: Do not use newer features

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, c++14

I am trying to compile some code with GCC and CMake. In the CMakeLists.txt file, I am setting the target properties like this:

```
set_target_properties(${example_name} PROPERTIES
        CXX_STANDARD 14
        CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED YES
        CXX_EXTENSIONS NO
        )
```

I would like to know how it is possible to force Cmake/Gcc to only use features available in C++14 and nothing newer. I would like a compile time error (not a warning). The reason I want this is that I will eventually need to port this code over to a different system with a compiler that only supports C++14.

To test the above, I add some obvious C++17 features:

```
namespace bob::hope {
void bar() {
  if constexpr (true) {
    return;
  }
}
}
```

But instead of giving me an error, it just throws a warning. Specifically, if I turn on some warnings:

```
add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
```

then I get

```
warning: nested namespace definitions only available with -std=c++1z or -std=gnu++1z [-Wpedantic]
warning: ‘if constexpr’ only available with -std=c++1z or -std=gnu++1z
```

But the code otherwise compiles without error.

So how can I configure Cmake to disallow newer language features?

Comment: What about `-pedantic-errors`? Did you already try this? [gcc - Options to Request or Suppress Warnings](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html)

Comment: Oh. I have never heard of that. Let me try.

Comment: Yes. That does it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Warning to Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24383796/convert-warning-to-error)

Comment: I don't think so because the question here is specifically about pedantic errors.